How to gracefully receive SPL tokens?
I currently have a protocol where, if someone makes a transfer, I can charge a fee on their SPL token transfer (e.g., transferring 100 SPL tokens and charging a 3 SPL token fee).
But how should I create my SPL token account? Do I need to manually create token accounts for 1000 mints in advance? What if there are 100,000 different mints? Should I still create them manually by ts? Is there a more elegant and efficient solution, or should I let the users bear the cost of creating my token account?

acutually,I’m very curious to know how platforms like Raydium handle this, and how they receive fees.

Generally you'll create a PDA for the asset at the time you create whatever handles the transfer in your protocol. Something like:
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        token::mint = some_mint,
        token::authority = your_program_pda,
        seeds = [
            SOME_SEED.as_bytes(),
            some_acc.key().as_ref(),
        ],
        bump,
    )]
    pub fee_vault: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>>,

If you aren't already creating an account per-mint already for some other purpose, then the best approach is probably to take the the ATA as something like
    #[account(mut)]
    pub fee_ata: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,

Then assuming you have a master "wallet" that all fees will go to, validate that the account matches:
let ata_expected = get_associated_token_address_with_program_id(your_fee_wallet, mint, token_program_id);

In terms of what to do if it doesn't exist in that approach, some protocols do what you described and init all the atas themselves, but most will just have the first person to call this ix pay the init rent, because it's pretty trivial, and pretty easy to slip the init ATA ix in the same tx just before this ix.

Thank you for your reply, but now I’ve thought of a solution, though I’m not sure if it’s better. I can use getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount on the frontend to get the token account for the current mint, and then pass it to my contract as ata. I don’t think it’s reasonable to make the first person who transfers bear the cost. What do you think of this approach?

And if I use what you suggested, making the first person initialize it, should I use init_if_needed?

Probably not. When you build the tx on the front end, just stick the init ATA ix in front of your ix if the ATA doesn't exist already.

Create a new project directory and file, index.ts, in your terminal with:
mkdir sol-get-accounts
cd sol-get-accounts
echo > index.ts
Initialize your project:
yarn init --yes
or
npm init --yes
Install Solana Web3 dependencies:
yarn add @solana/web3.js@1 @solana/spl-token
or
npm install @solana/web3.js@1 @solana/spl-token
Open index.ts in a code editor and add the following dependencies:
import { Connection, GetProgramAccountsFilter } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } from "@solana/spl-token";
